# Why haven't I earned the Curious badge?

Tags: support, badges

For some reason I don't understand, the site will not give me the Curious badge. The criteria for it states, "Ask a well received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record". I have asked 7 questions so far on Arqade, all of them having a positive number of upvotes and all of them on separate days. The badge tracker even displays it as if I have the criteria for it.

[image]

Can someone elighten me on why I haven't received it yet and what I need to do to receive it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a positive question record? Deleted questions still count against your positive record (even more so), so just deleting negative-scoring questions won't clear your record. If you click on the badge, you'll get a small popup like the following, which shows every requirement that needs to be met in order to earn the badge:

[image: My own progress towards the Socratic badge]

If you have a positive question record... it takes a while for the system to award new badges, you'll get yours soon enough.

Comment: Yeah it says I dont have a positive record. Which doesnt make sense to me either, as far as I can remember Ive never deleted a question. Is there anyway for me to check if I did, other than the past 60 days it already shows?

Comment: You have two deleted, closed, negatively scoring questions, so that is preventing you from having a positive record.

Comment: Well then.. I really dont remember those but honestly that doesnt surprise me. I'm a forgetful person. Thanks for looking into this for me, it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 7):

To add to @Wrigglenite's answer, a positive question score is [calculated the following way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

> (total questions - negative questions - closed questions - deleted questions) / total question >=.5

You have 2 questions that are deleted, closed, and downvoted, and 9 questions total, so you current score is

> (9 - 2 - 2 - 2) / 9 = .33

If you want the badge, you will have to ask 3 more positively received questions.

Comment: I actually spent time looking for how this was calculated not realizing it was already here